# Issues in Data Label

Tags: highcharts

I wanted to enable data labels in the chart I created. However, when I saw the graph all the data labels are not visible/drawn.  In this image you cannot see the data labels in all points

[image: screenshot of graph]

However as part of this post, I wanted to give the fiddle with the chart text that is generated for your reference. But when I ran that fiddle it seemed like it was working. I am not sure if I am missing any thing.

Another issue is the tool tip is gone. Can I not have tooltip along with the data labels? Data labels are essential for me since the downloaded images wont have tool tip and datalabels come handy. Tooltips are handly in web application.

Can any one help me in this here?

Here is the code from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/4/) I am talking about:

```
 plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: 'True'
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `enableMouseTracking: false`. Setting this means that HC will not listen to where the mouse is so it doesn't know where to put the tooltip. Turn this back on and tool tips will show.

Also, you have tons of dangling commas on your jsFiddle. Click on JSHint at the top to highlight them. Chrome and FF can sort of ignore them but other browsers like IE will throw errors.

Comment: By the way thanks for the comment and I have corrected the script for removing extra commas. But stil I am not getting the datalables for all the series. http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/5/

Comment: I just realized that the datalabels are not shown for 100% passrates. I am certain I am missing some settings here. Could any one guide me here please?

Comment: I see datalabels for 100% passrates on the fiddle in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [crop](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop) to show all datalabels.

Comment: Hi, I tried various options around the crop and it still does not work for me.